# AWS for PowerShell doesn't recognize the credentials file

Tags: windows-10, powershell, amazon-web-services

Calling `Get-Ec2Instance` returns:

> Get-Ec2Instance : No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.

I did however added the `credentials` file under `C:\Users\{user name}\.aws` directory

And when I call `Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail` I get the expected result:

> ProfileName StoreTypeName         ProfileLocation
>
> default  SharedCredentialsFile C:\Users{user name}.aws\credentials

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the existing credential file? I use the following:

```
Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey "YourAccessKey" -SecretKey "YourSecretKey" -StoreAs "MyCredential"
Get-EC2Instance -Credential (Get-AWSCredential "MyCredential") -Region ap-east-1
```

I'm not sure why they do it this way, but saving the credential to a variable doesn't work for me, and gives me the error you're seeing:

```
PS C:\> $AWScred = Get-AWSCredential -ProfileName "MyCredential"
PS C:\> Get-EC2Instance -Credential $AWSCred

get-ec2instance : No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
```

My credential type is `NetSDKCredentialsFile` though, which is encrypted and saves to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\RegisteredAccounts.json`.